# Connecting to MongoDB in Kubernetes pod with kubernetes-client using Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-python-client

I have a MongoDB instance running on Kubernetes and I'm trying to connect to it using Python with the Kubernetes library.

I'm connecting to the context on cmd line using:

```
kubectl config use-context CONTEXTNAME
```

With Python, I'm using:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config(
    context = 'CONTEXTNAME'
)
```

To connect to MongoDB in cmd line:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/mongo-mongodb 27083:27017 -n production &
```

I then open a new terminal and use PORT_FORWARD_PID=$! to connect

I'm trying to get connect to the MongoDB instance using Python with the Kubernetes-client library, any ideas as to how to accomplish the above?

Comment: use a mongodb client library

Comment: To clarify, you can easily connect to DB from terminal but you have issue using Python?

Comment: @PjoterS That's correct, I am able to connect without issue in terminal, but facing issues when using kubernetes-client in python to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Define a kubernetes service for example [like this](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/nodesjs-mongodb/mongo-service.yaml), and then reference your mongodb using a connection string similar to `mongodb://<service-name>.default.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to find out your DB Client Endpoint.

That could be achieved if you follow this article [MongoDB on K8s](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/)
make sure you got the URI for MongoDB.
(example)

`“mongodb://mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo,mongo-2.mongo:27017/dbname\_?”`

and after that, you can call your DB client in Python script.

```
import pymongo
import sys

##Create a MongoDB client
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://......') 

##Specify the database to be used
db = client.test

##Specify the collection to be used
col = db.myTestCollection

##Insert a single document
col.insert_one({'hello':'world'})

##Find the document that was previously written
x = col.find_one({'hello':'world'})

##Print the result to the screen
print(x)

##Close the connection
client.close()
```

Hope that will give you an idea.
Good luck!